# avg operation on repeated values

Tags: sql, select

I have two tables, employee and certified.

The certified table contains the list of employees certified to drive a plane. One employee may be certified for many planes and vice versa. Not all employees are certified.

Each employee draws a salary. **Only one salary**, no matter how many certifications.

How do i find the average salary of those employees who are certified for at least one plane?

My problem is,

```
SELECT AVG(SALARY) FROM EMPLOYEE E, CERTIFIED C WHERE E.EID=C.EID;
```

This includes a salary twice if the employee is certified for two planes. So AVG(salary) gives a wrong value.

I'm a newbie, so my apologies if my question seems too basic. Help?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And is salary same in each duplicate row for a given employee?

Answer (score 1):

You want a semi-join here. You can implement it with an IN predicate:

```
SELECT AVG(SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE EID IN (
             SELECT EID
             FROM CERTIFIED
             )
;
```

or with an EXISTS predicate:

```
SELECT AVG(e.SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
WHERE EXISTS (
             SELECT *
             FROM CERTIFIED AS c
             WHERE c.EID = e.EID
             )
;
```

The IN predicate will not work as expected if `CERTIFIED.EID` is nullable and indeed has nulls, although I would assume it would be unusual to store a certification in that table not associated with any employee.

Alternatively you could use a proper join (and I would recommend you seriously consider  switching to the proper join syntax too), only you would need to join to a set of *distinct* `EID` values derived from `CERTIFIED`, rather than directly to `CERTIFIED`. For the derived table you can use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT AVG(e.SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT DISTINCT EID
           FROM CERTIFIED
           ) AS c
    ON e.EID = c.EID
;
```

or GROUP BY:

```
SELECT AVG(e.SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
INNER JOIN (
           SELECT EID
           FROM CERTIFIED
           GROUP BY EID
           ) AS c
    ON e.EID = c.EID
;
```

Comment: I think I prefer the `JOIN` version.  And it's about the only time I'd use `DISTINCT`, too, given there's no aggregate to be calculated.

Comment: Yes, and DISTINCT lends itself very well to readability too in this case (well, in my opinion anyway).

Answer (score -2):

If an employee can have only one salary, I suggest

```
SELECT AVG(e.salary)
FROM employee e
WHERE e.id in (SELECT c.id FROM certified c)
```

This makes sure, that each eid is taken once. I still do not understand what the certified table is doing here. Do you need only those salaries of employees which are certified for flights?

Comment: Average salary *per employee* will not be affected by this join, but the *overall* average salary, which is what the OP is after, might.